# In java can super() be used to call any parent method or just the parent constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super

Is it possible to call any parent class methods using super() from child class method or super is used just for calling parent constructor

Answer (score 7):

For calling methods the syntax is `super.methodName()`. Just `super()` will call the constructor.

It's very similar to `this` keyword but for parent.

`this()` calls this classes constructor from another constructor. `super()` calls the parents constructor from childs constructor.

`this.methodName()` calls the method of the current class, `super.methodName()` calls the method of parent class.

**EDIT:** As @harry has mentioned in the comment, the parent's method should be visible to the child to actually be able to use `super.methodName()`. Private methods in the parent cannot be accessed.

Comment: scope visibility also needs to considered of parent method :)

Comment: I still didn't see the answer for OP's actual question in your answer. " `any parent class methods`"

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, `super.methodName()` can be used to access all visible parent class' methods. I have edited the answer.

Comment: "this.methodName() calls the method of the current class" Not necessarily. If the current object is of a subclass that has overridden `methodName` then it will call that one.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of Super keyword:

1. super()-only the super as a constructor call will call the super class default constructor
2. super(parameters)- calls only the parameterised constructors of its parent class.
3. super.methodName() - calls the method of its  parent class chain provided the method visibility is either public or protected.
4. If a subclass constructor invokes a constructor of its superclass, either explicitly or implicitly, you might think that there will be a whole chain of constructors called, all the way back to the constructor of Object. In fact, this is the case. It is called **constructor chaining**, and you need to be aware of it when there is a long line of class descent

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to further clarify:
Any constructor always calls the constructor of its super class before doing anything else. So, you can't put any code before your super(...) call, and you can't omit a super(...) call neither. Even when you don't put one explicitly in your code, it will still call one (the default constructor in that case). - So, it's not like that constructor chain can be avoided. It's always there. There also isn't a convincing reason for putting `super()` without arguments in your constructor, except maybe for readability.